# Convert dict to nested list, inserting keys into each sublist

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

I have a solution to this question, but I'm curious if there might be a better way.
I have a dict like this:

```
dict1 = {
'key1':[['value1','value2','value3'],['value4','value5','value6']],
'key2':[['value7','value8','value9'],['value10','value11','value12']],
'key3':[['value13','value14','value15'],['value16','value17','value18']]}
```

I want to convert this into a nested list, and inserting the keys into the new sublist like this:

```
nestedlist = [
['value1','value2','key1','value3'],['value4','value5','key1','value6'],
['value7','value8','key1','value9'],['value10','value11','key2','value12'],
['value13','value14','key2','value15'],['value16','value17','key2','value18'],
['value10','value11','key3','value12'],['value13','value14','key3','value15'],
['value16','value17','key3','value18']]
```

I solve this the following way:

```
keys = [*dict1]
newlist = []
for item in keys:
    for item2 in dict1[item]:
        item2.insert(2,item)
        newlist.append(item2)
```

so, how can i improve this piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way via a list comprehension:

```
res = [[w[0], w[1], k, w[2]] for k, v in dict1.items() for w in v]

# [['value1', 'value2', 'key1', 'value3'],
#  ['value4', 'value5', 'key1', 'value6'],
#  ['value7', 'value8', 'key2', 'value9'],
#  ['value10', 'value11', 'key2', 'value12'],
#  ['value13', 'value14', 'key3', 'value15'],
#  ['value16', 'value17', 'key3', 'value18']]
```

Comment: this method was the fastest, ill give  you the correct answer :)

Comment: I was trying list comprehension at first but for some reason couldn't get it even though I've done multi nested list comp before. Thanks for posting this

Answer (score 1):

I would've done it pretty similarly. The only differences shown here:

```
result = []
for k, l in dict1.items():
   for ll in l:
      ll.insert(2, k)
      result.append(ll)
```

No need to do list unpacking or doing [] accessing on dict1. `items()` returns a list of tuples containing each key and value of the dict.

Comment: Maybe there's something you can do with list(), map(), and lambdas but I'm not near a machine with python on it to test it out